# service-worker timestamp is incorrect

Tags: service-worker

my service-worker is not activating on page reload.
While trying to figure out the reason I noticed that in Chrome it shows 1/1/1970
as receive date and I think this could be a reason. Who knows why receive date is incorrect and does it really affect on service-worker activation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but sometimes date is correct. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that date is used in the DevTools interface. (If you'd like, you can address that issue by filing a bug.)

I don't believe that the date has anything to do with the actual behavior you're seeing, though. What it looks like is that you have an active service worker, and a newly installed service worker that's in the `waiting` state. That's normal, and the new service worker will remain in `waiting` until one of two things happen: all open clients controlled by the previous service worker is closed (reloading isn't enough), or you call `self.skipWaiting()` from within the new service worker.

There's more details about this scenario at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#waiting